# How can you convert the protobuf response from application/protobuf (grpc over http)

Tags: google-chrome, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a server that receives and responds grpc methods over HTTP successfully. When I open the network tab on Chrom dev tools I get the responses but they are all binary format (I think?). Is there a way to decode them into human-readable format? I do have the proto definitions at hand if that could help.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that it would require code of some sort running in the browser, that the Chrome dev tools can debug. Another approach could be WireShark. It's possible to add bespoke dissectors to Wireshark if you're prepared to compile it oneself. This can include message deserialisers in code generated from your proto definitions. So, you'd be seeing the data in WireShark instead of Chrome, but that could be OK. https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Protobuf